# How to run AWS ECS RunTask API from PostMan

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, rest, postman, amazon-ecs

I'm trying to hit the AWS ECS RunTask API endpoint and I'm able to leverage the aws-sdk in asp.net and hit the endpoint (as recommended by AWS) but I have this feeling that I'd avoid setting up an endpoint for this if we can just hit this using Postman.

```
AmazonECSClient client = new
AmazonECSClient(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
RunTaskRequest req = new RunTaskRequest()
{
Cluster = "XXXXX-XXX",
TaskDefinition = "XXXXX-XXX:1",
LaunchType = "EC2",
Overrides = new TaskOverride
{
TaskRoleArn = "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXX:role/XXXXXXXX"
}
};
return client.RunTaskAsync(req).Result;
```

Trouble is, signing this request using postman is very hard and I can't find any documentation on it. Any opinion or help that you can provide? Can I use an API Gateway, or sign the Postman Request? If yes, how?

Comment: Could you use the CLI instead of postman?

Comment: @Fermin Yeah, that works too. But I want to create an endpoint for this that's accessible to a team. The other idea I have is to use Lamba for the snippet above and API gateway but that seems to be an overkill.